# Browsing Web page (.aspx page) from a remote PC

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am unable to browse a simple asp.net page from a remote PC through the IP address of that computer. However IIS is responding on a local computer with http://localhost and even when I type the local computer's IP address where the page is present.
Computer is running XP and IIS 5.1

The message displayed on browser is "The server is taking too long to respond" however the page is just "Hello World" which displays local time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your website on IIS is bound to "All Unassigned" and not just to localhost.

[IIS 5 http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/8115/msiis535b15d.gif](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/8115/msiis535b15d.gif)

Change the "IP Address" field from the above panel to "All Unassigned".

Comment: Are these settings in IIS Administration?

Comment: Yes, check the screenshot I attached to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so so so much Daniel. It's fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the computer doesn't have a firewall enabled or that the port 80 is allowed?, you should check that IIS is listening on all network interfaces as well.

Since you are talking about using XP i would bet that the windows firewall is the guilty.

Comment: The firewall is the one which comes with XP (Windows own Firewall) but how can I find that IIS is listening on all Network interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your IP/firewall settings? If they are OK try 'netstat' to see whether it really listens on remote port+network interfaces (and not localhost only). On linux it would be 'netstat -nlp' to see servers listening, but cannot check for windows, I just remember that they differ.

Run netstat --help to see the option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Visual Studio web server vice IIS, it wont allow you to connect remotely.